# How can I use Matlab's filter command to plot impulse response of system?

Tags: matlab, plot, filter, sequence

I am trying to make a plot the impulse response of both an IIR and FIR system by using Matlab's filter command and no other pre-existing Matlab functions. The filter must be able to handle a sample input such as plot([1 2 2], [0 1 .8]). The problem looks like this:

```
function iplot(b, a)

% IPLOT Impulse response of system.
% IPLOT(B,A,N) is the N-point impulse response
% of the filter B/A:

%                          -1                -nb 
%     
%           B(z) b(1) + b(2)z + .... + b(nb+1)z
%
%    H(z) = ---- = --------------------------------- 
% 
%                          -1                -n         
%           A(z) a(1) + a(2)z + .... + a(na+1)z


% If h[n] FIR, then N = length(h);

% given numerator and denominator coefficients in vectors B and A.

% N is specified according to the following rule:

% If If h[n] is IIR and increasing (i.e. |h[n]|-->inf as n-->inf),

% then N=20;

% h[n] is IIR and decreasing (i.e. |h[n]|-->0 as n-->inf), 

% then the maximum N is determined such that

% rms value of h(1:N) = 0.999 * rms value of h(1:1000).

% However, in this case, N must also be chosen such that 10 <=

% N <= 100
```

This is what I have so far. I know its not correct and right now it doesn't plot anything but its as far as I've gotten. Any Help is much appreciated!

```
h = filter(a,b,[1,zeros(1,999)]); 
N = length(h); 

plot(h, zeros(length(h),999), 'b'); 

poles = roots(a); 

if poles <= 1

    N = 20; 
    plot(h, N, 'b'); 

end


end
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What is wrong with the code you produced? The first 3 lines look like they should do exactly what you described (although your x and y axes might be flipped from what is traditionally expected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of code is correct.  However, you need to **reverse** the order of `b` and `a` when calling `filter`.  `b` stands for the numerator coefficients while `a` stands for the denominator coefficients.  That's in your docstring too.

You are correctly specifying the input as being a single input.  However, your plotting code isn't correct.  How `plot` works is that it takes in a set of `x` values and a set of `y` values and we plot those points as pairs.  Because you are plotting a discrete output signal, I would recommend you use `stem` instead of `plot`.  This way, each point gets drawn with a line that goes from the horizontal axis up to the point of interest.

In any case, you need to provide a set of `x` values.  Specifically, you want a vector that goes from 0 up to 999.  The `y` values consist of the output impulse response due to `filter`.  Currently, your `x` values contain the output impulse response and your `y` values are a bunch of zeroes.  This will be visualized as a whole bunch of points being clustered at `y = 0` which is probably not what you want.

Therefore you simply need to do this:

```
h = filter(b,a,[1,zeros(1,999)]); 
plot(0:999, h, 'b');  %// Change
```

With regards to my recommendation, I would use `stem` instead:

```
stem(0:999, h, 'b');
```

The last part of your code is plotting the poles of your filter.  You should also make a **separate** figure and plot those results instead.  You're not doing this, so what happens is that when you try and plot the poles, the figure that contains your impulse response **will be overwritten**.  Calling `plot` multiple times with the current window open will overwrite the plot with the last invocation to `plot`.  Therefore, spawn a new `figure` window before proceeding:

```
figure; %// New window
h = filter(b,a,[1,zeros(1,999)]); 
stem(0:999, h, 'b');  %// Change

figure; %// New window
poles = roots(a); %// Find roots
%// Plot the roots as single dots
plot(real(poles), imag(poles), 'b.');
```

---

However, this doesn't answer your problem statement.  The problem statement says:

> If `h[n]` is FIR, then `N = length(h)`;
>   given numerator and denominator coefficients in vectors `B` and `A`.
>
> `N` is specified according to the following rule:
>   If `h[n]` is IIR and increasing (i.e. `|h[n]|-->inf as n-->inf`),
>   then `N=20`;
>
> `h[n]` is IIR and decreasing (i.e. `|h[n]|-->0 as n-->inf`),
>   then the maximum N is determined such that
>   the `rms` value of `h(1:N) = 0.999 * rms value of h(1:1000)`.
>   However, in this case, `N` must also be chosen such that `10 <= N <= 100`

We know that a FIR filter is when you specify `A` to be 1 or just a single value.  When you detect that the length of `A` is 1, then `N = length(h);`.  However, if `a` is **not** just a single value, we have to check for two cases.  The first case is when the impulse response is increasing.  You can check that by using `diff` and making sure that all neighbouring differences of your impulse response are positive.  The next case is when `h` is decreasing.  You can check that by making sure that all the neighbouring differences of your impulse response are negative.

If it's the increasing case, then choose `N = 20`.  If it's the decreasing case, then choose the `N` value to be what you saw above, and you can use the [`rms`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/rms.html) function in MATLAB to help you do that.  We also need to make sure that this value is between 10 and 100, and we'll also want to **round** the value as we are trying to choose an integer number of points and `rms` will probably give you a floating point number.

Therefore, perform `filter` with the default 1000 points, then you'll need to **truncate** the response depending on what the inputs are into the function.  First we need to check for FIR, then the IIR cases to decide what values of `N` to display.

Therefore:

```
figure; %// New window
h = filter(b,a,[1,zeros(1,999)]); 

%// Decide on the value of N
if length(a) == 1
    N = length(h);
else
    d = diff(h);
    if all(d >= 0) %// Check for increasing
        N = 20;
    else %// Decreasing case
        %// Find RMS value
        N = round(0.999*rms(h));

        %// Ensure that 10 <= N <= 100
        if N < 10
            N = 10;
        end
        if N > 100
            N = 100;
        end
    end
end

%// Plot just up to the first N values
stem(0:N-1, h(1:N), 'b');  

figure; %// New window
poles = roots(a); %// Find roots
%// Plot the roots as single dots
plot(real(poles), imag(poles), 'b.');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! The stem plot clarifies a lot! However my figure two still doesn't seem to be plotting anything and my Figure 1 is really clustered. could this be due to my axis not being formatted correctly? Perhaps I should be using linspace somehow?

Comment: @KarmaPimp - Check my edits.  I forgot to account for the case of choosing `N`.  Figure 1 is clustered because we are plotting too many points!

Comment: Oh i see, yes that makes since. I thought perhaps you didn't need to do that anymore with your solution but I am a little confused as to why your not using stem anymore instead of plot?

Comment: @KarmaPimp - Yes sorry.  I mean to use `stem`.  Copy and paste error.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Yes, the did help, very greatly!! Thank you so much. Take care :D